# How to save and load the object's list to SharedPreferences with/without using Gson?

Tags: java, android, gson, sharedpreferences

In my Android app, I used Gson in order to save/load the object's Arraylist in SharedPreferences. Follows are my code using Gson.

```
public static ArrayList<RequestModal> getModalList(Context ctx) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString("ModalList", new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<>()));
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<RequestModal>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

In here "RequestModal" is the simple object include a bit of strings and integers.
It works well in case "online". But if internet is offline, forever works on below code.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<RequestModal>>() {}.getType();
```

How can I solve it? What is the way implement the feature like this with/without using Gson? Please help me anyone having a good idea.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It works well in case "online". But if internet is offline, forever works on below code. ---> I am not getting you here. How is your code dependent on internet?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My code independent on internet. But once network is offline, it forever works on "TypeToken<ArrayList<RequestModal>>() {}.getType();", not stop or crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this without Gson:

```
public static EpisodeDetails parseEpisodeDetails(String content) {
    EpisodeDetails episodeDetails = new EpisodeDetails();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
        episodeDetails.title = jsonObject.getString("title");
        episodeDetails.subTitle = jsonObject.getString("subtitle");
        episodeDetails.synopsis = jsonObject.getString("synopsis");
        episodeDetails.ends_on = jsonObject.getString("ends_on");

        JSONArray images = jsonObject.getJSONArray("image_urls");
        if (images.length() > 0) {
            episodeDetails.image_url = images.getString(0);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return episodeDetails;
}
```

What I'm doing is just taking the String, in your case the one saved on the shared prefs called `ModalList` and inserting the values on my structure, on my code the structure is called `EpisodeDetails`, on your code the correspondent is `RequestModal`. If you don't want to do it via code and want to try another library I recommend Jackson.

Another thing, on this line:

```
String json = getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString("ModalList", new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<>()));
```

Your second parameter is not necessary. `getString` takes the key to load as first parameter and  a default value as second paramter (in the case of empty result). You could change this to `""` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, another solution to your problem could be [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo). It makes use of `Gson` to save `ArrayLists` of objects in `sharedPrefs`, its usage is so simple as:

```
Person person = new Person("john", 24);
tinydb.putObject("user1", person);

ArrayList<Person> usersWhoWon = new ArrayList<Person>();
tinydb.putListObject("allWinners", usersWhoWon);
```

and that's it, check out my link given above to see the usage details.